# How to add "plates" to gnome-control-center

Tags: c++, c, gnome-shell

There's a discussion here about why this isn't easily done:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/108060/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-items-to-system-settings-window

That discussion is a little old. Is there an gnome upstream supported way to do this yet? I'd really like to be able to do this cross-platform, if possible.

Edit:
Someone voted this off topic and not related to programming, so I'll provide more detail...
I'm looking to write a settings "plate" in C that can be integrated into gnome-control-center. There was more detail in that article about adding icons to the menu using the .desktop file. I'm not talking about that.